# how to handle POST requests in razor pages

Tags: c#, razor

I'm trying to POST data to Razor Page, but the OnPost never get's invoked. It works fine with OnGet, but not POST (for some reason).

I've tried defining HttpPost without luck.

I use Postman to test.

Page:

```
@page
@using FFU.Home.Galaxy.Models;

@{
    @functions {
        public void OnPost([FromBody] EmailDataModel model)
        {
            string test = "t";
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class EmailDataModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Data:

```
[{"Name":"Name","Value":"bfdbd"},{"Name":"Email","Value":"bdfk@nvfdk.se"},{"Name":"Content","Value":"vd"}]
```

Comment: where is your controller ?

Comment: What url are you posting to?

Comment: What happens if you change your Data to be only one EmailDataModel instead of an array? (something like: {"Name":"Name","Value":"bfdbd"})

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was an issue with Anti-forgery token. I don't need that feature for this site so I added IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute and it worked as expected.

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1).AddRazorPagesOptions(o =>
            o.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `[HttpPost]` property

Like this for post request

```
   [HttpPost]
    public void OnPost([FromBody] EmailDataModel model)
    {
        string test = "t";
    }
```

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't work for some reason.